# Beamer class notes

Tags: beamer, uncover

I am preparing notes for a class using `beamer` in LaTeX. I use `\uncover` pretty liberally for answers. Is there a way to print notes for students that doesn't have answers. Here's a sample of my code:

```
\section{Week 1}
\subsection{Basic Definitions}
\begin{frame}{Example: Marijuana Legalization}
\\
A local radio station is interested in determining how North Carolina 
residents feel about marijuana legalization.  The station set up a special 
phone number which could be called by  people  who  wished  to  voice  their  
opinion.   The  station  found  that  67\%  of  the  1,624 callers support 
legalization.

\begin{itemize}
\item What is the parameter of  interest?\\ \uncover<2->
{{\color{wolfred}proportion of all North Carolina residents who support 
marijuana legalization}}
\item What is the population?
\\\uncover<3->{{\color{wolfred}All North Carolina residents}}
\item What is the statistic?\\\uncover<4->{{\color{wolfred}67\%, the 
proportion of callers who support the legalization of marijuana.}}

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Get used to use  blank lines (or `\par` if you prefer avoid the empty lines) instead of `\\\`  to break paragraphs, even when, like in this example, the result will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use beamer modes for this. Change the overlay specification for `\uncover` from `<2->` to `<beamer:2-|handout:0>` and for the handouts for students add the option `handout` to the documentclass.

```
% presentation
\documentclass{beamer}
% handout for students without answers
%\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\section{Week 1}
\subsection{Basic Definitions}
\begin{frame}{Example: Marijuana Legalization}

A local radio station is interested in determining how North Carolina 
residents feel about marijuana legalization.  The station set up a special 
phone number which could be called by  people  who  wished  to  voice  their  
opinion.   The  station  found  that  67\%  of  the  1,624 callers support 
legalization.

\begin{itemize}
\item What is the parameter of  interest?\\
  \uncover<beamer:2-|handout:0>{{\color{red}proportion of all North Carolina
  residents who support marijuana legalization}}
\item What is the population?\\
  \uncover<beamer:3-|handout:0>{{\color{red}All North Carolina residents}}
\item What is the statistic?\\
  \uncover<beamer:4-|handout:0>{{\color{red}67\%, the proportion of callers
  who support the legalization of marijuana.}}
\end{itemize}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```